# Numpy - Creating a function whose inputs are two matrices and whose output is a binary matrix in Python

Tags: python, function, for-loop, numpy, matrix

I am trying to write a function that take two m x n matrices as input and gives a binary matrix output, where 0 is returned if an element m,n is less than zero and returns 1 if else. I want these binary values to replace the values that were evaluated as negative or else in an array or matrix format. Here is my code that has produced errors thus far:

```
def rdMatrix(mat1, mat2):
    mat3 = np.dot(mat1,mat2)
    arr = [[]]
    k = mat3(m,n)
    for k in mat3:
        if k < 0:
            arr.append[0]
        else:
            arr.append[1]
```

I am having difficulty in telling the function to map a new value to each element in the matrix and then store it in an array. I'm also having trouble defining what a specific element of m x n is in the for loop. I am new to programming, so please forgive me for any obvious mistakes or errors that will easily fix this function. Also, please let me know if there is anything that needs clarification.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is NumPy, so you can obtain binary matrices using comparison operators.

For example, your code can be implemented very simply as

```
mat3 = np.dot(mat1, mat2)
return mat3 >= 0
```

Comment: Thanks. Just out of curiosity, is there an easy way to format the Boolean values such that they are 1 and 0 instead of False and True?

Comment: You can convert the result with `.astype(int)`.